# Setting locale separately on sign up page and after logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have an app with user authentication where I want store locale in user model. I want to have language selection in two places - on the sign in page and in user profile page.

I want the app to behave in the following way:

1. *User logs in for the first time*: their preferred language is set based on the language they've chosen on the sign up/register view.
2. *It's not the first time user logs in*: locale is taken from user model, so if user changed language from Russian to English on sign up page but has Russian set as the chosen language in their profile, app will disregard the choice of the language on the sign up page and it will be displayed in Russian after logging in.

In app controller I have of course method set locale which looks like this at the moment:

```
def set_locale
  if current_user
     I18n.locale = current_user.locale 
  else
     I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

So now to my question: how should I manage setting the locale on sign up page? And how to keep this information while logging in? Cookie? Params? 

On the login page I have two views - sign in view and registration view. If I switch language on sign up page and go to registration page, I'd like to keep the new language their as well.

Comment: Sounds interesting. What code have you written so far?

Comment: I've done it but I'm not sure it's the best way to do so as my codes is getting repeated. I've created 2 links on sign_up page, and if user chooses a language I store this information in a cookie. In set locale in else part I did 'I18n.locale = cookies[:language] || I18n.default_local'. I added method 'set_language' in omniauth and sessions controller and during every login I check if the user has already set preferred language, if not, I choose the one stored in cookie (if it's present) or go for a default one.

Comment: ooh, sorry - it's a bit hard to tell from a verbal description. We can help you with it, but it'd be easier to read if you edit your question and add the code there so we can see it.